Metronic 8 step buttons in wizard form doesn't work (react)
in Metronic 8
step buttons in wizard form doesn't work
<button type='button' className='btn btn-lg btn-primary me-3'>
  <span className='indicator-label'>
    {stepper.current?.currentStepIndex !==
      stepper.current?.totatStepsNumber! - 1 && 'Continue'}
    {stepper.current?.currentStepIndex ===
      stepper.current?.totatStepsNumber! - 1 && 'Submit'}
   <KTSVG
      path='/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr064.svg'
      className='svg-icon-3 ms-2 me-0'
    />
  </span>
</button>

i copied files project\src\app\modules\wizards to my registration form the continue button dosen't work
i want to help me fix this problem
